# array initialization - conditionally

Tags: c++, c, arrays, if-statement, initialization

I have an 8 membered array which has to be defined conditionally. ie, for each condition, the values of the elements of the array will be different.

However, for each condition, I'd rather not define the elements one by one. Is there any way where I can define all the elements of the array together like this:

```
double c[8];
if ( a == p ){
    c[]={values} ; 
} else if ( a == q) {
        c[]={values} ; 
} else if (.. ){
        ......
}
```

instead of

```
double c[8];
if ( a == p ){
    c[0]= .. ;
    c[1]= .. ;
    ...
    c[7] = ..;
} else if ( a == q) {
    c[0]= .. ;
    c[1]= .. ;
    ...
    c[7] = ..;
} else if ( ... ) {
    ....
}
```

PS: There are 7 if conditions.

Comment: Perhaps knowing `values` would assist in solving this one.

Comment: they are double precision values varying between 1 and -1. eg {0.458401,0.0,0.0206768,-0.0118135,0.115635,-0.0842532,-0.00355449,0.0412016} for one of the cases.

Comment: In that case, predefined values arrays are my recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the values in each branch of the condition are not changing:

Have some value arrays values[NumConditions][8] and making c a pointer.
Then:

```
switch(a) {
    case First: c = values[0]; break;
    case ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `values` are defined on compile-time, you can use `std::copy` for example.

```
std::copy(std::begin(values), std::end(values), std::begin(c));
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepare 7 arrays (or just a two-dimensional), which will be initialized at compile-time. Then, declare a pointer `c`. Afterwards, use a `switch` to select the desired array (i.e. `c = valuesList[2]`). If you need to write on that array, copy its contents outside of the `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

Much cleaner approach .Use Switch case to avoid unnecessary comparisons

```
switch( a)
{
case p:
       c[]={value1,valu2,...} ; 

}
```

This is just an demo how to use:

int main()
   {

```
   int choice = 1;

   switch( choice )
   {
        case 1: double c[8] = {0.123,32.33,33.02,66.44,0.11,45.08,44.9,0.0412};
        break;      
   }

   return 0;
```

}

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Gives
warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
error: assigning to an array from an initializer list

Comment: int main()
   {
       
       int choice = 1;
  
       switch( choice )
       {
            case 1: double c[8] = {0.123,32.33,33.02,66.44,0.11,45.08,44.9,0.0412};
            break;      
       }

       return 0;
   }

Comment: @BirajBorah I think you may be getting this error if you are defining the array separately to its initialization. i.e. You have `double c[8];` on its own. In this case you would need to use rounded brackets rather than curly brackets to initialize the array: `c[8] = (0.123,32.33,33.02,66.44,0.11,45.08,44.9,0.0412);`.

Answer (score 0):

If all initializers for a given condition are the same then you can use class std::array instead of the array. For example

```
std::array<double, 8> c;

if ( a == p ){
    c.fill( 0 ); 
} else if ( a == q) {
        c.fill( 1 ) ; 
} else if (.. ){
        ......
}
```

Comment: All the initializers are different.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO create eight functions which you can give meaningful names that tell the next programmer (or yourself in one year) what the different eight configurations mean.

I admit it is a bit verbose but more importantly it makes the code clearer

```
if ( a == p )
{
  setConfigValuesForProducingPannkakes(c);
}
else if ( a == q )
{
  setConfigValuesForProducingWaffles(c);
}
...
```

Comment: I do it in the code. But when I try to post some questions, I try to put it in general terms.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::array<double, 8> c;
if (a == p) {
    c = {values};
} else if (a == q) {
    c = {values};
} else if (...) {
    ...
}
```